# Classic Email Template in Lightning Component - Insufficient Privileges

Tags: visualforce, lightning-aura-components, lightning-experience, email-template, dynamic-visualforce

I used visual force components in classic email templates. Now I need to view those email templates in Lightning. So I have created Lightning component custom action to create a pop up and used iframe to get visual force components dynamically. But the issue is I am able to view email templates in pop up as System Administrator but not using other profiles.If I try to view email templates using other profiles I am getting error as Insufficient Privileges Error. I have given access to Visual force component's controller to the profile as well. Am I missing something else.Kindly suggest.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure but please check 'Manage Public Classic Email Templates' and 'Manage Public Lightning Email Templates' permissions on other profiles. I think they need to be true to access email templates.